# Retrieving a JSON valid string from a python requests.post()

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am extremely confused after trying a few possible solutions and getting various errors that just lead me in circles. I have a function that will grab a tweet, put it in a dictionary, then write that dictionary to a file using `dumps` like so:

```
jsonFile = {}
jsonFile["tweet"] = tweet
jsonFile["language"] = language

with open('jsonOutputfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(jsonFile, f)
```

I then have another python file that has a function that will return the value of this `jsonOutputfile.txt` if I want to use it elsewhere. I do that like so:

```
with open('jsonOutputfile.txt') as f:
    jsonObject = json.load(f)
return jsonObject
```

This function sits on my localhost. The above two functions that have to do with saving and retrieving the JSON file are separate from the rest of my functions below, as I want them to be.

I have another function that will retrieve the values of the returned status using python requests, like so:

```
def grab_tweet():
    return requests.post("http://gateway:8080/function/twittersend")
```

and then after grabbing the tweet I want to manipulate it, and I want to do so using the JSON that I should have received from this request.

```
r = grab_tweet()
data = json.dumps(r.text)
return data.get('tweet')
```

I want this function above to return just the value that is associated with the `tweet` key in the JSON that I received from when I saved and loaded it. However, I keep on getting the following error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'` which I am confused about because from my understanding using `json.dumps()` should create a JSON valid string that I can call get on. Is there an encoding error when I am transferring this to and from a file, or maybe when I am receiving my request?

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Here is a sample of a response from my `requests.post` when I use `r.text`, it also looks like there is some Unicode in the response so I put an example at the end of the tweet section. (This also doesn't look like a JSON which is what my question is centered around. There should at least be double quotes and no U's right?):

`{u'tweet': u'RT THIS IS THE TWEET BLAH BLAH\u2026', u'language': u'en'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[.json()](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content)** in requests module to get response as JSON

**Ex:**

```
data = r.json()
return data.get('tweet')
```

**Note:** *json.dumps* convert your response to a string object

*Edit as per comment* - Try using the ast module.

**Ex:**

```
import ast
data = ast.literal_eval(r.text)
```

Comment: usong `r.json()` I get this error: `simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quores: line 1 column 3 (char 2)`

Comment: Can you post a sample of your response?

Comment: Yup, posted a sample of what my response looks like as an edit

Comment: Updated snippet. Can you try with the `ast` module?

Comment: hmm, it seems like using ast.literal_eval doesn't change anything sadly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171550/discussion-between-cjnash-and-rakesh).

Comment: I cannot access chat

Comment: Huh, that is odd, anyway: No, I am not getting an error, just getting the same looking string as if I didn't use ast. Also,
I am fairly certain that the problem lies in the saving and loading of the JSON, because when I return what I get from the load function, I get a format that isn't valid JSON

Comment: `data` is a dictionary after `data = ast.literal_eval(r.text)` you can now do  `data.get('tweet')` without getting the error

Comment: Wow, that worked like a charm. Thank you so much for your patience and help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `.json()` method. See requests' documentation: [JSON Response Content](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content)

Also, for future reference, rather than do

`f.write(json.dumps(jsonFile))`

You could simply use:

`json.dump(jsonFile, f)`

Same with using `load` instead of `loads`:

`jsonObject = json.load(f)`

Comment: @cjnash The bit you posted is not valid JSON. How did you get it? Strings you should using " " instead of u' '.

Comment: I got it using the functions outlined in my question. I understand that it is not valid JSON and that is my question. I created a dictionary, dumped it to a file, then loaded it. So somewhere in that process, it is being converted.

Comment: @cjnash If your gateway returns JSON, then use `.json()` rather than `.text`: `r = grab_tweet()` `r.json()['tweet']`

Comment: Doing that unfortunately throws this error: `ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`. I am pretty sure I have to use ast.literal_eval() which worked just as Rakesh pointed out. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: @cjnash Why not fix your gateway to return valid JSON though?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, and I have been trying to fix it for the past day and no answer I have read has helped me, so at this point I am just frustrated and if Rakesh's answer gives me the correct end result I am fine with that.